# nginx: Is there a maximum "client_max_body_size"?

Tags: nginx

I've looked through the nginx technical documentation, and there's no real mention of a *maximum* plausible/possible `client_max_body_size` ... but I was wondering if there was? Could it be, for example, 1TB? (Don't ask why!)

Answer (score 1):

(The "why" would help answer the "real" question if there is one hidden here. ;))

On most platforms it's a 64 bit number putting the limit around 9EB, on some others it's a 32 bit number putting the limit at around 2GB. However, there are other factors that will have an affect on the request body size, such as buffering settings and memory page sizes, before you get to those large sizes.

Comment: Yes, I wonder how much "file" can be in memory on the client side...